# Stop giving links to posts in reviews

Tags: feature-request, review

What is the purpose of detecting whether the reviewer is paying attention to the post if the link to the actual post is given? If the link is given, one can open the actual post and review it according to the current status and pass the test.

Comment: If they did that, I would stop reviewing altogether. No context, no review. Plain and simple.

Comment: If you clicked the link, the audit worked as expected.

Answer (score 13):

Because the links are extremely useful for reviewing *actual* posts by quality reviewers.

If the mechanism to get rid of the bad reviewers (in this case, removing the link to the post) ends up stopping good reviewers from doing their jobs, then that mechanism is more harmful than it is helpful.

Answer (score 11):

One of the reasons that there are audits is to check whether you are paying attention and to stop robo-reviewers, people that just click on the "No Action Needed" button without actually reviewing. They just will click on that button, and not even click on the link to see the current status. If you click on that link and review according to the current status, then actually you passed the test because you paid attention.